# $\nabla f$ (grad/del) of a multivariate function with a time variable t among other variables

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Let's say we have a function that is multivariate.
We have both spatial variables and a time variable.

Given:
$\nabla f(r, t)$

Now my question is do we partially differentiate (partial derivative) with respect to time or does $\nabla$ only consider spatial variables (partial derivative w.r.t time is omitted/ignored)?
I guess the same applies to the Laplace operator $\nabla ^2$?

Comment: The author should make this clear, because otherwise it's ambiguous. It's just a convention that needs to be made. In my experience most often the convention is that $\nabla$ operates only on the spatial variables.

Comment: I've heard/seen different opinions regarding this, and from what I understand another symbol is used when partially differentiating w.r.t. other variables than the spatial ones. But I can't say for sure.